# Why does adding a type to a gradle task impact the println statements in the example below?

Tags: java, gradle

**Build**:

```
task taskX() << {
    println 'taskX'
}
task taskY(type:Copy) << {
    println "taskY"
}
```

**Output:**

```
C:\dev\how-to-confluence\NYSSIS-WS\ear>gradlew -q taskX
taskX
C:\dev\how-to-confluence\NYSSIS-WS\ear>gradlew -q taskY
C:\dev\how-to-confluence\NYSSIS-WS\ear>gradlew -version

------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 2.10
------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:   2015-12-21 21:15:04 UTC
Build number: none
Revision:     276bdcded730f53aa8c11b479986aafa58e124a6

Groovy:       2.4.4
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.3 compiled on December 23 2013
JVM:          1.7.0_67 (Oracle Corporation 24.65-b04)
OS:           Windows 7 6.1 amd64
```

**Note:**
The println calls in taskY do not output.

Comment: What does the type:Copy in the parameter do?

Comment: @JFMeier https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/tasks/Copy.html

Comment: The task of type copy does not require `<<`. Remove those and the behavior will be as you're expecting.

Answer (score 0):

In order to provide feedback that files are in fact copying I needed to to take advantage of the [eachFile closure](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/tasks/AbstractCopyTask.html#eachFile(groovy.lang.Closure)) available in the copy task.

```
task taskX() << {
    println 'taskX'
}

task taskY(type:Copy) {
    eachFile{
        println "taskY"
    }
    from 'src/main' into 'build'
}
```